# limit of sequence/series in the form [infinity/ infinity]

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose I have a series/sequence
$\{A_n\}$, ${n \to \infty}$ and the limit of the $A_n$ is:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}A_n = \infty$$

Is it possible to find a sequence/series which will give

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{A_{n+1}}{An}= 0$$

(I am aware that the limit will be in the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$)

Answer (score 1):

If $(A_n)$ is a positive sequence with $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{A_{n+1}}{A_n}= 0$, then there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac{A_{n+1}}{A_n} <1$ for $n \ge N$. This gives

$A_{n+1}<A_N$ for all $n>N$.

Therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty}A_n = \infty$ can not occure.

Answer (score 0):

If $(A_n)$ is a positive sequence with $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{A_{n+1}}{A_n}= 0$, then by the ratio test: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ converges, hence $A_n \to 0$.

Comment: ok, and what about a case when a the limit of a  sequence An is infinity,Is it possible that the limit of An+1/An will be infinity too?

Comment: yes, $A_n=n! $.